# Set default value of date_field only if current value is empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using the same form in a partial to both create a new object and modify it. I have the following field:

```
<%= f.date_field :dob, class: 'form-control' %>
```

I know that I can set its default by adding `value: Time.now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')`, but I want to do this if and only if the current value is empty. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly check if its nil, and provide today's date.

Lets say the form is for @person

```
<%= f.date_field :dob, value: @person.dob || Date.today.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"), class: "form-control" %>
```

Answer (score 1):

suppose, this form for user then,

```
<% date = @user.dob.present? ? @user.dob : Time.now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') %>

<%= f.date_field :dob, value: date, class: 'form-control' %>
```

Hope this will help you.